# Bespoke Wordpress Contact Form Parse

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form

I have built a multiphase contact form within my theme on it's own unique page called hire-page.php I have also created a seperate javascript file called multiphase.js in order to make the different phases work on the form. 
This page is located within my js folder!

At the bottom of my multiphase.js file I have added this function...

```
function submitForm(){
    _("multiphase").method = "post";
    _("multiphase").action = "https://www.mysite.uk/parse-page.php";
    _("multiphase").submit();
}
```

Naturally when I submit my form it natually goes to my parse-page.php page but for some reason I am not getting any emails or for some reason the html is not showing up on that page.

Am I losing something here or do you have any other ideas?
Many thanks

Comment: Are you getting just a white page after the submit? If so, it sounds like you have a syntax error in your parse-page.php. You may want to post that as well.

Comment: Aha Yes you was right there Cuagau! It was a ';' that i did not put in my parse script!